# pandas convert year,quarter to integer

Tags: python, string, pandas

In pandas I have a column of data in the following format:

```py
Period
2018 Q1
2018 Q2
2018 Q3
2018 Q4 
2019 Q1
2019 Q2
2019 Q3
2019 Q4
...
```

Currently dtype format is object/string. Is there a way to convert the data to int64? I don't necessarily need datetime format, however if it is the only solution it's fine.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the integer equivalent of '2018 Q1' ? Can you post your expected output ?

Comment: I am happy with '2018 Q1' or '2018-Q1' or similar. I just need the data in int/int64 as I find easier to work with the dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simpliest should by replace `Q` to empty string and then convert values to integers:

```
df['Period'] = df['Period'].str.replace(' Q', '').astype(int)
print (df)
   Period
0   20181
1   20182
2   20183
3   20184
4   20191
5   20192
6   20193
7   20194
```

If want datetimes or quarters periods use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with whitespaces, [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and for periods [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Period'].str.replace('\s+', ''))
df['Per'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Period'].str.replace('\s+', '')).dt.to_period('Q')
print (df)
    Period      Dates     Per
0  2018 Q1 2018-01-01  2018Q1
1  2018 Q2 2018-04-01  2018Q2
2  2018 Q3 2018-07-01  2018Q3
3  2018 Q4 2018-10-01  2018Q4
4  2019 Q1 2019-01-01  2019Q1
5  2019 Q2 2019-04-01  2019Q2
6  2019 Q3 2019-07-01  2019Q3
7  2019 Q4 2019-10-01  2019Q4
```